# what simple_list_item_1 mean?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when I use simple_list_item_1 in the array adapter does it mean it is replacing my existing layout with an android pre-defined layout

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Comment: Check out the article here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to be able to ask questions better in the future

Answer (score 1):

With these lines you are preparing the adapter for the list:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
  this, // the current context
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // the layout for each item from the list
  words // the list
);
```

So basically, the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is a pre-defined layout which contains a TextView. When the adapter is attached to the list then only the list will be populated with elements from your list (`words`) - it will not replace your layout for the Activity or Fragment.